# Design using 64 SK6812 LEDs - Matrix vs 8x8 matrix

Tags: led-strip, led-matrix

I am designing a 64 LED ring and am curious about the advantages of a matrix design for addressable LEDs.

For example, if I want to use 64 SK6812s, what is the difference between connecting all of them in series and designing an 8x8 matrix?

Comment: your question is based on a false assumption that SK6812 can be connected in a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressable LEDs must be wired in series if you want to individually address them.  Depending on what you mean by "matrix", they'd either no longer be individually addressable or would simply not work.

Comment: Only for the serial non-id protocols.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind answer. Right, that totally makes sense. I opened Neopixel 8x8 matrix schematics (Addafruit) and confirmed that all the less are connected in series. 

Thanks again!!